# Invalid Response Error with Alexa SDK v2

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

For 2 days now, I have the issue that my lambda function using the ask-sdk-core v2.0.2 returns invalid responses.

A very simple setup:

`HelloIntent` is handled by `HelloIntentHandler`:

```
const HelloIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'HelloIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Hello back';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

When I call this intent, the simulator goes straight to:

> There was a problem with the requested skill's response

Using the ErrorHandler, I checked and the results of `handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.error` are:

```
{ type: 'INVALID_RESPONSE',
message: 'An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill.' }
```

Question: What is the problem here? When I open the skill using the invocation name, the `LaunchRequestHandler` gets called and responds properly, but any other intent does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the problem, it is sort of difficult to deduct from the above error:

```
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloIntent';
},
```

In the `canHandle` function, you need to check for the request type and intent name.